# Is it possible to embed the few bits of image is watermarked in histogram of audio?

Tags: image, audio, histogram, signal-processing, watermark

I have an image of size 2097152 bits and histogram of an audio file with 205 bins. then How will the watermarking perform in which bits of an image is embedded into a histogram?
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: good question. it will help if you post something that you have tried.

Comment: Actually, I haven't tried about this because this is new to me. I had an idea about that`s I asked.